# how to calculate the difference and store?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, difference

I want to calculate the difference store in a variable.

**Sample DB:**

```
Id   RS
--   --
1    10
2    25
3    33
4    44
.    .
.    .
```

I want to calculate the difference between 1&2 , 2&3, 3&4 (ID) and I have to store the total into a variable. (`25-10 = 15, 33-25=8, 44-33=11`)
And the output should be 34.
I am stuck on the given below code.

**Code:**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   RsTableAdapters.tbl_RS_detailsTableAdapter sd;
   sd = new RsTableAdapters.tbl_RS_detailsTableAdapter();
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();     
   dt = sd.GetData();
   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {                
         string rsValue = (row["RS"].ToString()); // here getting first value (10)
     }
}
```

Comment: You have to make sure that your returned data is sorted on ID to make this work

Comment: Observation to maybe save you some time: as it appears from your description, you are using each entry but the first and last exactly two times, once with + and once with -. So they cancel each other out, and your final sum is just the difference between the last value and the first value. As in your example 44 - 10 = 34 (and not 29, as you have 25-10=10 for some reason)

Comment: @Andrei : I understood what you said, do we have any other option?

Comment: @Reshma, of course, see DrKoch's answer below.

Comment: Something like this is very simple too `var result = Enumerable.Range(1, dt.Rows.Count- 1).ToList().Select(i=> Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]["RS"]) - Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i-1]["RS"]))).Sum();`

Answer (score 2):

You could use linq for that:

```
var differences = from row1 in dt.Rows
join row2 in dt.Rows on (int)row1["ID"] equals (int) row2["ID"] + 1
select (int)row2["RS"] - (int)row1["RS"];
var sumofdiffs = differences.Sum();
```

As long as "RS" and "ID" are integers if not you should parse it first. This approach does not require sorted elements by ID, its downside - the complexity O(n^2), pro - simplicity.

**Edit:**
As pointed the complexity may be even better than O(n^2), if linq will be able to use hashes in equality condition it could get amortized O(n) so simpler than the preparation of sorted data O(n log n).

Comment: This should even be better than O(N^2) because `join` is intelligent and uses hash tables under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: It remembers the value of the previous row to calculate diff and sum at each row except the first.

```
 int sum = 0;
 int diff;
 bool first = true;
 int oldValue;
 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {                
     int value = row["RS"];
     if(!first)
     { 
         diff = value - oldValue;
         sum += diff;
         first = false;
     }
     oldValue = value;
 }
```

You have to make sure that your returned data is sorted on ID to make this work

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var drs = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
int last = (int)drs.Last()["RS]
int first = (int)drs.First()["RS"]
int diff = last - first
```

As others have said, you need the data to be sorted by ID.

```
Select RS from tbl_RS_details order by ID
```